# error while building Nutch 1.10

Tags: ant, ivy, nutch

I am  trying  to build nutch 1.0 using ant on win7 platform. However, I am getting the below error.

```
[ivy:resolve]           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]           ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]           :: org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12;1.6.1: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: log4j#log4j;1.2.15: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: commons-lang#commons-lang;2.6: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: commons-collections#commons-collections;3.1: not foun
d
[ivy:resolve]           :: commons-httpclient#commons-httpclient;3.1: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.3: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.9: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-core;1.2.0: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: org.apache.tika#tika-core;1.8: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: com.ibm.icu#icu4j;55.1: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: xerces#xercesImpl;2.9.1: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: xerces#xmlParserAPIs;2.6.2: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: oro#oro;2.0.8: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: com.google.guava#guava;11.0.2: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: com.google.code.crawler-commons#crawler-commons;0.5:
not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: org.apache.cxf#cxf;3.0.4: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: org.apache.cxf#cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws;3.0.4: not found

[ivy:resolve]           :: org.apache.cxf#cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs;3.0.4: not found

[ivy:resolve]           :: org.apache.cxf#cxf-rt-transports-http;3.0.4: not foun
d
[ivy:resolve]           :: org.apache.cxf#cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty;3.0.4: no
t found
[ivy:resolve]           :: com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.5.1: no
t found
[ivy:resolve]           :: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat#jackson-dataformat-c
bor;2.5.1: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs#jackson-jaxrs-json-provid
er;2.5.1: not found
[ivy:resolve]           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]
[ivy:resolve]
[ivy:resolve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS

BUILD FAILED
C:\nutch\build.xml:476: impossible to resolve dependencies:
        resolve failed - see output for details

Total time: 6 seconds
```

I tried many forums but to no avail. Not sure what's causing this or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall? That would block downloads unless you configure ANT to use a proxy.

Comment: I am not able to build the source.

Comment: yes.... and building the source depends on 3rd party dependency jars, downloaded by ivy. So again, are you behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: yes I am behind a corporate firewall.